# PHP login requires refresh

Tags: php, cookies, web, authentication

I have a webpage that shows a login form depending on whether a cookie is set. If the user logs in, the data is sent to a login script which sets the cookie and returns the user back to the original page. The problem is, for some reason, despite the cookie being set correctly (or deleted, in the case of logout), the page continues showing the old content. A refresh is required for the page to actually show the correct info. What's going on?

My login script effectively does this:

```
setcookie("my_cookie",$userID, time()+3600*24*356, "/");
```

and my page checks this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["my_cookie"]))
```

at the very top of the page.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I hope, you're not relying on the user ID to determine that a user is logged in. Use sessions for this.

Comment: Paste your actual code and not some extract line btw

Comment: Did you make sure that the redirect is actually refreshing the page, and not just telling your browser to load it again (which, in that case, it might load from the Cache).

It happened the same to me when setting up a basic login... Check if the problem happens when in *incognito*

Comment: @Nico Yep, it happens in incognito as well. I user header('Location: index.php'); to redirect. Is there a way to tell it not to use a cached copy?

Comment: @BorisGuéry I'm not, I just put that up there as a placeholder for what I actually use.

Answer (score 0):

Use session for this. Session are stored without refresh.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a cookie, server send header to browser to set cookie (this is reason why you can't set cookie after send any data - header must be first). When browser send request for page, sends all cookies in request header.